# Sorting list of tuples using merge sort?

Tags: python, python-3.x, mergesort

I am trying to sort this list of tuples after the number on the second index using the merge sort algorithm, but I am very unsure on how to do so.

This is the list of tuples I am trying to sort:

```
list_of_tuples = [('Birds of Prey', 97.1),
                  ('Dolittle', 175.0),
                  ('The Gentlemen', 7.0),
                  ('Falling', 22.0)]
```

And I can implement a general merge sort algorithm, but i cannot do it in a way where I sort after the number in the tuple on the second index.

This is my implementation of a general merge sort:

```
def merge_sort(arr):
    if len(arr) > 1:
        mid = len(arr) // 2
        left = arr[:mid]
        right = arr[mid:]
        merge_sort(left)
        merge_sort(right)

    i = j = k = 0
    while i < len(left) and j < len(right):
        if left[i] < right[j]:
            arr[k] = left[i]
            i += 1
        else:
            arr[k] = right[j]
            j += 1
        k += 1

    while i < len(left):
        arr[k] = left[i]
        i += 1
        k += 1

    while j < len(right):
        arr[k] = right[j]
        j += 1
        k += 1

    return arr
```

How would I make this fit the problem?

The prefered answer is that it returns the tuple with the highest number in the end, so the result would be `('Dolittle', 175.0)`.

Comment: If you use the provided sort function, that is covered early on in key functions in the docs https://docs.python.org/3.3/howto/sorting.html Although it's not actually a merge short. If you're asking how to implement it, then two answers are "don't," and write a sort function that takes a key or comparison function as an argument.

Answer (score 0):

You could follow [Python's sort implementation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted) and add a `key` argument:

```
def merge_sort(arr, key=lambda x: x):
    if len(arr) < 2:
        return arr

    mid = len(arr) // 2
    left = arr[:mid]
    right = arr[mid:]
    merge_sort(left)
    merge_sort(right)

    i = j = k = 0
    while i < len(left) and j < len(right):
        if key(left[i]) < key(right[j]):
            arr[k] = left[i]
            i += 1
        else:
            arr[k] = right[j]
            j += 1
        k += 1

    while i < len(left):
        arr[k] = left[i]
        i += 1
        k += 1

    while j < len(right):
        arr[k] = right[j]
        j += 1
        k += 1

    return arr
```

then all you need to do is: `res = merge_sort(list_of_tuples, key=lambda x: x[1])`

Or with python's sort implementation: `res = sorted(list_of_tuples, key=lambda x: x[1])`

Comment: when i do this, the i get the error:

```
    while i < len(left) and j < len(right):
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'left' referenced before assignment

```

Comment: Your indentation is incorrect, you need to get the code from the point i=j=k inside the if condition

Comment: ah yeh, that i see now.
But when i do that code now, it returns this
```[('Falling', 22.0), ('The Gentlemen', 7.0), ('Birds of Prey', 97.1), ('Dolittle',175.0)]``` Which is not the desired outcome, as i would have it completely sorted, then return the max amount

Comment: assign an output variable to your merge_sort function like this : output = merge_sort() and just print out output[-1]

Comment: @Cal thx, but how would i fix it so it is completely sorted. when i run it, it says

```
[('Falling', 22.0), ('The Gentlemen', 7.0), ('Birds of Prey', 97.1), ('Dolittle', 175.0)]
```

instead of it being completely sorted

Comment: @AbhishekKulkarni Yes, but if i add another value to the tuple, it wont show the largest value anymore, and the Gentlemen movie with 7.0 as a number would show instead